# Highcharts - Display only specific series in specific category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible using Highchart's various options to only display specific series columns in specific categories. I'm trying to split data up in groups, but not all groups will have data for all series, and with a large number of Categories and Series, it is reserving a ton of space for every series in every category, and I would like to have it simply not render specific columns in specific categories, if possible.

Also I'd like to know if I'm doing this incorrectly, conceptually speaking, and should approach this from a different angle. I realize I could make this a single-series chart with categories cleverly named, but I'm trying to group these things visually together, not to mention the reports themselves are being generated by a proprietary generator, so it is hard to "know" what kind of data is coming back, in terms of how a human would want to see it.

You can see an example here:

Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/gmpa7f7h/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['West','East','North','South']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {

            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Oneill',
            data: [3,0,0,0]
        }, {
            name: 'Jackson',
            data: [5, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Tealc',
            data: [0, 9, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Carter',
            data: [0, 9, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'McKay',
            data: [0, 0, 11, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Hammond',
            data: [0, 0, 2, 0]

        }, {
            name: 'Mitchell',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 5]
        }, {
            name: 'Bratak',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 2]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, so what you want is basically the bars you have in your fiddle, but without all of the extra space being left for the series that are null for a give X value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use (abuse) the `stack` series option from the documentation example you started with:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Oneill',
        data: [3,0,0,0],
        stack: 'left'
    }, {
        name: 'Jackson',
        data: [5, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'Tealc',
        data: [0, 9, 0, 0],
        stack: 'left'
    }, {
        name: 'Carter',
        data: [0, 9, 0, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'McKay',
        data: [0, 0, 11, 0],
        stack: 'left'
    }, {
        name: 'Hammond',
        data: [0, 0, 2, 0]

    }, {
        name: 'Mitchell',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 5],
        stack: 'left'
    }, {
        name: 'Bratak',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 2]
    }]
```

It's not terribly elegant and makes assumptions about the shape of your data, however. With some more information about what you're after in the end, there might be a better, more generalizable solution.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that could work. The only issue I see immediately is that you can still hover over zero to see the other options, but not sure that really matters.

Edit: Apparently enter submits. Anyway, that really is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm really surprised there isn't a way to just group related data better together, beyond doing something like this.

Comment: Finally able to come back to this. Your suggestion worked like a charm, after a few minor tweaks to how I was setting things up. Thanks a ton.